# Overloading operator < for non-random iterators

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

I wanted to know if we could overload the `operator <` for non-random `iterators` like those of `std::list`, `std::map`, etc. Say for example if I overload it for `std::list` then :

```
bool operator < (std::list<T>::iterator &i1, std::list<T>::iterator &i2)
{
    return (&*i1 < &*i2);
}
```

My main purpose is to do an iteration like this :

```
for (auto i = l.begin(); i < l.end(); ++i) // possible for std::vector, std::deque, etc
// I want to do this instead of i != l.end()
```

But the compiler says :

> [Error] declaration of `operator<` as non-function

Anyone has any solutions ?

Comment: Any reason you just don't use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: the above iteration ie using `< operator` is more effective than those cases when we use `i != l.end()` hence i want to know if this thing works

Comment: @AnkitAcharya How could `operator <` be more effective than `operator !=`?

Comment: What?  Most of the standard library is based of of using `!=` So I doubt it is faster to use `<`.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya, is it possible to share whole code so that i can debug it. i think compiler doesn't look to the scope of custom `operator<` as `i<l.end()` expression's both arguments are in the std namespace. you may put your custom operator into std namespace to test this idea.

Comment: the `operator <` is effective when you are doing multiple deletions from the `container` in a range. it can be visible when you are deleting the `last element` & the `iterator` goes through an increment `++i`.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya `l.end()` is not the last element but one past that.

Comment: One before that @Lingxi

Comment: @Lingxi what is your point ?

Comment: If you are deleting elements out of a container you should be using the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) which uses [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) which also uses `!=`

Comment: If the last element is deleted, then `l.end()` also changes

Comment: *If the last element is deleted, then l.end() also changes* You got to be kidding me...

Comment: @AnkitAcharya *References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.* See this [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase).

Comment: @AnkitAcharya & Lingxi, it doesn't matter what changes & what not, does anyone have the answer of this question ?

Comment: I am going to join the chorus. < for list iterators does not make sense. For all you know, they are not even guaranteed to be increasing! That is, the element at the begining of the list might easily reside at a higher address in memory than the one at the end.

Comment: Emulating random access for a non-random-access container is impossible, and your supposed performance optimisation sounds like a myth.

Comment: @CppNITR It is not possible. Template argument for `T` cannot be deduced from the iterator type, and the underlying (actual) type of the iterator is not specified in the standard.

Comment: May be `operator <` wont be effective over `!=` in cast of `std::list` but it does work better in case of `std::deque` & `std::vector`. Just check this (cpp.sh/4yki). Replace in fuctions `check_low_fuel`,  `landing`,  `departure` the `<` symbol in the loop condition with `!=` & see

Answer (score 3):

You are working in the wrong direction. Non-random-access iterator does not support `operation <` for a reason. Basically, it is not possible to implement `operation <` in a rational way for non-random-access iterators. In your case, you should write:

```
for (auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i)
```

instead. Or, if C++11 is supported, consider the possibility of using a range-based for loop.

As to your code:

```
bool operator < (std::list<T>::iterator &i1, std::list<T>::iterator &i2)
{
    return (&*i1 < &*i2);
}
```

It is not OK in two ways.

1. `std::list<T>::iterator` is a dependent name. You need to qualify it with `typename`.
2. Template argument for `T` cannot be deduced from the iterator type. It must be specified explicitly.

So, how to solve the second issue? Well, I don't think it is possible. The actual type of the iterator is not specified in the standard, and is considered an implementation detail.

Comment: he explained why he prefer this way, please look to the comments. I know your reasoning hence i don't want to downvote. however, suggestion is not an answer, you should write to the comments.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş OK. I'm going to provide an implementation in the answer, anyway.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş Well, I just find that I'm unable to provide an implementation that makes sense. So, I just provided the template, leaving the implementation to others.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş if you look closely I too have done the same thing but alas ! I failed

Comment: @MuratKarakuş, those reasonings are not sound.

Comment: C++11 is required for `auto` anyway.

Comment: There is a hackish solution, though. Knowing your implementation you know what the actual type of the list iterator is, and so you can use it like that (gcc 4.8.3 variant):
`template <class Tp> bool operator< (std::_List_iterator<Tp> lhs, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

It just doesn't make sense to do a less than comparision on iterators that do not provide it.  Using your example with a `std::list` the nodes of the list could be anywhere in memory.  Trying to  compare the addresses of the nodes is pointless as the first node could have a higher address than all of the other nodes.  If that is the case then you would never loop through the list.  The only way this works is to have a sentinel node(`end`) and every iteration check to see if you are not equal to it.  By doing this you know you have not reached the end and you can continue.  Once you compare equal to the `end` then you know you have reached end of the list.

Comment: It may not make sense but the idea is quite novel and I think we should appreciate the thought of this kid

Comment: `deque` also works like a `list` implicilty but it has an overload for `<` but why not list then. there is definitely something we aren't getting well

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Kindof, It could be but a `deque` also has constant time access to any element of the `deque` so it is typically implemented as a vector of vectors.

Comment: May be `operator <` wont be effective over `!=` in case of `std::list` but it does work better in case of `std::deque` & `std::vector`. Just check this `(cpp.sh/4yki)`. Replace in functions `check_low_fuel`, 'landing', `departure` the `<` symbol in the loop condition with `!=` & see

Comment: @AnkitAcharya The code you posted has undefined behavior as you are altering the contents of the container which is invalidating your iterators.  If you want to see a comparison of speed of `!=` vs `<` then see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1abd29d4d4fe033).  It is basically a tie with `!=` faster in all cases except 1

Comment: @NathanOliver  i  dont  find  any undefined behaviour in my code,  if it had been, it would have done the same with `<`. But in such cases it hasnt crashed or given any strange output even once

Comment: @AnkitAcharya You don't have to believe me but if you ask on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) they will tel you it does.

Comment: @NathanOliver how do i remove the undefined behaviour then

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `std::remove_if` (and then `erase` of course), this is much clearer what you are doing and should also be efficient. If you can use C++11 then the predicate can be a lambda and it's really compact.